# Database design with split and merge logic

Tags: database-design

My machine learning project predicts when is the right time to do rail track maintenance. I need to design a table to store the model prediction. The model runs every 6 weeks and produces a CSV which I am planning to save in PostgreSQL.

| Id | Track_Id | Start KM | End KM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | First | 1 | 5 |
| 2 | First | 11 | 16 |
| 3 | Second | 6 | 8 |
| 4 | Third | 18 | 30 |

I need to allow the user to make changes on the start and end KM and the data will be saved for 2 years. Scenarios to consider:

1. Users can split the startKM and endKM that so they can do maintenance on one of them now and the next one later.
2. Users can merge the track startKM and endKM so they can do the maintenance together.
3. When the model runs again there will be different startKM and endKM which I can either merge with the original if it fits between the existing startKM and endKM from the backend or have it as a separate row. I need to highlight in the UI that something changed from the last run.

This is the design I have come up with so far. Not sure If there is any better way or whether this design will cover other scenarios that might come up later. I need to maintain the previously predicted model outcome and also the changes on top of it.

| Id | Track_Id | Start KM | End KM | SegmentId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | First | 1 | 5 | s1 |
| 2 | First | 11 | 16 | s1 |
| 3 | Second | 6 | 8 | s2 |
| 4 | Third | 18 | 30 |  |

Segment

| Id | TrackId | Action | ActionId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| S1 | First | merge | a1 |
| s2 | Second | split | a2 |

Action

| Id | segmentId | trackId | Start KM | End KM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | s1 | First | 1 | 16 |
| a2 | s2 | Second | 11 | 13 |
| a2 | s2 | Second | 14 | 15 |